# Android , Could we use Parse LocalDataStore for local Storage?

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-database, local-datastore

As we all know parse server being shutdown, but if i want to use parse local data store concept without any parse server interaction(without calling parse `initialize(context,appkey,masterkey))` , then how could we achieve this?

Please suggest me if we can use it or not? If not , any best option apart from parse server for local data store?

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Parse local datastore without parse backend. Objects do not get an objectid until the device is in contact with the Parse backend. Parse pinning is meant as a convenience addition to the backend; not as a replacement.

If you're now considering using ONLY parse local datastore, you should replace your solution with Core Data instead. Or consider setting up your own Parse server at i.e. Heroku.